# How do I extract specific words from a string in a text file? c++

Tags: c++

my assignment is to take a string from a text file and count the number of words in it. I've gotten that far but now we have to be able to take a certain number and display that number word to the console. Say my string is "Hello World" if I enter '2' it should give me the result "World". I'm not really sure how my function should look for this. This is my code so far.

```
void getFileInfo(ifstream &inFile);
string words(ifstream &inFile);
int numOfWords(ifstream& inFile);


int main() {

    ifstream inFile;
    string sentence, fileName;
    int numCount, word;

    getFileInfo(inFile);
    numCount = numOfWords(inFile);
    inFile.clear();  // resets file pointer from the beginning
    inFile.seekg( 0 );
    sentence = words(inFile);

    cout << sentence << ": has " << numCount << " words in it" << endl;
    cout << "Enter a number to extract a word: ";
    cin >> word;


}

void getFileInfo(ifstream &inFile){

    string fileName;

    do{

        cout << "Please enter the filename: " << endl;
        cin >> fileName;

        inFile.open(fileName.c_str());

        if(!inFile){

            cout << "Invalid try again" << endl;

        }
    }while(!inFile);

}

string words(ifstream &inFile){

    string words, theWords;

    getline(inFile, words);
    cout << words;



    return theWords;

}

int numOfWords(ifstream& inFile){

    string fileName, words, str;
    int numCount =0;

    while(inFile >> words){
        ++numCount;
    }

    return numCount;


}
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You already have a function that reads one word at a time from the file and counts them.  What is wrong with using that same approach and testing whether the count is the number you are looking for, and then returning the word?

Comment: Extract the words to a `std::vector<std::string>`. Then grabbing the Nth worth just becomes `string_vec[N - 1]`.

Comment: There happens to be a fairly simple way to do this kind of a thing. Just take out a blank sheet of paper, and write down using brief, simple sentences in plain English, a step-by-step process of doing this. When done, [schedule an emergency appointment with your rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). After your rubber duck approves your proposed plan of action, simply take what you've written down and translate it directly into C++. Mission accomplished!

Comment: Can you think of a way to somehow save what you read from the file, in a container such as a vector or an array? Once you do that you'll have this: `["Hello","World"]`. Now if I query against this container, like the example you showed, and ask you for 2, what would you do to return the second word? Remember, containers are 0 indexed. Think about it!

Comment: thanks for the response, we aren't allowed to use arrays or vectors since the professor hasn't covered it yet in class. @cliqer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest slightly different code for your task. First, write some simple helper functions:

```
// Clear error flags (EOF, for example) and reset stream to the beginning.
void resetStream(ifstream& stream) {
    stream.clear();
    stream.seekg(0, ios_base::beg);
}

// Count the words in text file stream.
int getWordsCount(ifstream& stream) {
    int count = 0;

    while (stream) {
        string tmp;
        stream >> tmp;
        if (!tmp.empty()) ++count;
    }

    resetStream(stream);

    return count;
}

// Read word by specific number.
string getWordByNumber(int number, ifstream& stream) {
    string word;

    while (number--)
        stream >> word;

    resetStream(stream);

    return word;
}
```

Now you can easily get the number of words in a file and display a specific word by its number. For example:

```
int main() {
    string fileName;
    cout << "Enter the file name: \n";
    cin >> fileName;

    ifstream stream(fileName);

    if (!stream)
        cout << "Failed to open file!" << endl;
    else {
        int totalCount = getWordsCount(stream);
        int currentCount = 0;

        cout << "Total words count: " << totalCount << "\n\n";

        do {
            cout << "Enter the word number (enter '0' to finish): ";
            cin >> currentCount;

            if (currentCount == 0) break;
            else if (currentCount > totalCount)
                cout << "Invalid value!\n";
            else {
                string wordByNumber = getWordByNumber(currentCount, stream);
                cout << "Word by number: " << "'" << wordByNumber << "'\n";
            }

            cout << "\n";
        }
        while (true);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Warning:** This code is not very efficient and I have not tested it much. If you have any problems, be sure to write a comment.

Comment: this looks way more efficient than mine thank you. Can you explain the 'getWordByNum' function to me? I'm having a hard time understanding how its working. Like what does the '(word--)' do for it? thank you! @Grandbrain

Comment: The idea of this function is simple: we read the words from the file, counting them, and when the counter is equal to the number of the word we need, we return the last word we read. But instead, we can just read the file `number` to zero times. Say the word number is 1 (we need the first word). Then, the loop `while (number--)` does the following: _first_, it is checked that the `number` variable is not equal to zero, _after that_, the value of the variable is decreased by one. This is just a short version of the following code: `while (number > 0) { stream >> word; number = number - 1; }`.